# How to split dataframe made from objects?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I want to split one column pandas dataframe that look like this:

```
    0
0   38 A
1   35 B
2   14 B
```

into two columns:

So it can look like this:

```
    Number  Letter
0   38        A
1   35        B
2   14        B
```

But its showing type as:

```
0    object
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this a couple of ways and possibly more:

Using: `df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s\s+')` capture dataframe above.

#### Option 1 (Use string accessor and split):

```
df['0'].str.split(' ', expand=True).set_axis(['Number', 'Letter'], axis=1)
```

#### Option 2 (use string accessor and extract with named groups regular expressions):

```
df['0'].str.extract('(?P<Number>\d{2})\s(?P<Letter>[A-Za-z]{1})')
```

#### Output:

```
  Number Letter
0     38      A
1     35      B
2     14      B
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for this but unfortunately is not working in this case. Im getting TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str and I dont know how I can change type of my original values from first df

Comment: @Aly Can you post df.to_dict() to the question, so I can see your exact dataframe structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df['0'].str.split(' ',1).tolist(), columns = ['Number','Letter'])
print(df)
```